# how to make django default user when using formsets

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have this model that i want to make the `create_by` default for current user

```
class order(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None,null=True,blank=True)
```

in Django models I cant use `request.user`

I tried in `views.py` but i cant do it since i am using modelformsets

**I tried this**

```
def create_order(request):
    orderformset = modelformset_factory(order, form=orderForm)
    queryset = order.objects.none()
    user = request.user
    formset = orderformset(request.POST or None,queryset=queryset)

    if formset.is_valid():
        created=formset.save(commit=False)
        created.User = request.user
        created.save()

        return redirect('home')
```

> How i  can give default user to this orders  using modelformsets

Answer (score 0):

In Your models file, use foreign key for user as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class order(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in your views wherever you handle GET request, intialize the form as such

```
def create_order(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        initial = {'created_by':request.user}
        form = orderform(initial=initial)
        context['form'] = form 
        ...
```

Then When you're handling the POST Request, just pass the POST and save it

```
def create_order(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = orderform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ...
```

This is How I'd handle This Scenario in django, Try out Class Based View. Its very good once you learn its abstract methods.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Order(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

I Use hidden input to hide the input field, You can leave it open if you want. it will appear as a ChoiceField

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'created_by': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

views.py

I use the Create view and override get initial method to pass user as initial value

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Order

class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'order_create.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['created_by'] = self.request.user
        return initial
```

order_create.html

```
...
<form method='POST'>
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

...

Comment: @Andharsh    context is not defined